# VBA Script for scraping data doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have written a short VBA Script that generates URLs and downloads the content of the page and puts in a new worksheet. However, the data is always shown on two pages, yielding the following types of URLs:

For the first page of results:

```
resultat_annuaire.php?loc=01&item=hopital&session=clear   (with 01 being the region)
```

For the second page:

```
resultat_annuaire.php?loc=01&item=hopital&page=2   (session=clear is gone, replaced by page=2)
```

When my VBA script generates and scrapes URLs of **first pages** it works fine (i.e. I get 95 different pages downloaded to my excel)

But, when I run the same VBA script (only changing the way I generate the URL to get second pages) it downloads 95 times the content of page 2 of the first URL.

Now I have tried to simply fiddle with the URL in my web browser by doing the following:

Entering a second page URL:

```
resultat_annuaire.php?loc=01&item=hopital&page=2
```

And then changing 01 to 05 like so:

```
resultat_annuaire.php?loc=05&item=hopital&page=2
```

And again, nothing happens, the page remains the same i.e. as if I didn't switch the 01 to 05.

Here's the VBA script:

```
Sub Data_scraping()
    For x = 1 To 9
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;" _
            & "http://etablissements.hopital.fr/resultat_annuaire.php?loc=" _
            & "0" _
            & x _
            & "&item=hopital&session=clear" _
            , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))


        '.CommandType = 0


        .Name = "resultat_annuaire.php?loc=01&item=hopital&session=clear"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
    Rows("1:31").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A5").Select
Next x
End Sub
```

Could anyone provide an explanation or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro works very well for **page=2**,

```
Sub sof20287920Data_scrapping()
  Dim x, strLoc, strUrl
  Dim wkb

  Set wkb = Workbooks.Add()
  wkb.Activate

  For x = 1 To 9
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    strLoc = "resultat_annuaire.php?loc=" & "0" & x & "&item=hopital&session=clear&page=2"
    strUrl = "http://etablissements.hopital.fr/" & strLoc
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "URL;" & strUrl _
      , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))


      '.CommandType = 0


      .Name = strLoc
      .FieldNames = True
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .PreserveFormatting = True
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
      .RefreshPeriod = 0
      .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
      .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
      .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
      .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
      .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
      .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
      .WebDisableRedirections = False
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
    Rows("1:31").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A5").Select
  Next x

End Sub
```

Even for page=2, session=clear seems requird, like this:

```
http://etablissements.hopital.fr/resultat_annuaire.php?loc=01&item=hopital&session=clear&page=2
```